# Searching through objects in array swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to create a search function using the UISearchController. However i cant seem to make it work with my Team Object. I've started by creating a Team Object which contain a id, name and shortname. Then i'm retrieving the teamData from a url and adding the Team Objects into an array which is populated into a tableView. This tableView contain a searchController which is suppose to filter the Data, but nothing happens.

arrays

```
var teamArray = Array<Team>()
var filteredTableData = [String]()
```

GetTeams function

```
func getTeams(url: String) {

    isApiCalling = true
    request(.GET, url, parameters: nil)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            if error == nil {

                let data: AnyObject = data!
                let jsonArray = JSON(data: data as! NSData)
                for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {



                        // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
                        var newTeamObject = Team(id: subJson["id"].intValue, name: subJson["name"].stringValue, shortname: subJson["shortname"].stringValue)


                        self.teamArray.append(newTeamObject)


                }


                self.isApiCalling = false
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

            }
    }

}
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("teamCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamCell


    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 20)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.teamArray[indexPath.row].name as String



    if (self.cellSelected.containsObject(indexPath)) {
        cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryCheck
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryUncheck
    }


    return cell
}
```

FilterData

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (teamArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Team Objects

```
class Team{
  var id: Int!
  var name: NSString!
  var shortname: NSString!


init(id: Int, name:NSString, shortname: NSString) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.shortname = shortname

}

}
```

Comment: Hey i have the same problem. I have followed your way, at first, I Got array cannot be bridged and then I have added let array: NSArray. At the end i get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at the filteredTableData. please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The objects in the teamArray don't have a SELF property. You can't use SELF to search in all the properties of the object at once. You have to give the name of the property, and if you want to search in more than one you have to add all those properties to the predicate.

I would think it's enough for you to search in the name property like so:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
```

If you need in more properties you do like this:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR shortname CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text, searchController.searchBar.text)
```

Comment: Hmm do i need somehow to connect the searchBar with the updateSearchResultsForSearchController function

Comment: Here's a tutorial to help you set properly the SearchController, so that the updateSearchResultsForSearchController gets called: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: Okay i missed the searchUpdate. error now: warning: object 0x7ff3aafc0e00 of class 'Striky.Team' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Striky.Team valueForKey:]

Comment: If you want to avoid the error "does not implement methodSignatureForSelector" you need to inherit your class from NSObject

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the definition of your Team object, and any sub-objects that it contains? (TeamData).

Also indicate where you expect the search text to appear in your team object.

I haven't used NSPRedicate a lot, but my understanding of the CONTAINS comparison is that it checks an individual field to see if it contains a substring. I don't think it will check all fields of the objects you're searching. That seems like what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchWord)
self.filteredArray = self.array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```