# Array is empty after the conversion of NSArray to Swift Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nspredicate

I am playing around with Swift recently. I am doing a search function with custom TableView. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940885/searching-through-objects-in-array-swift) guy in order to make my search work perfectly, but I a problem at the conversion from NSArray to Swift Array.

Here is my code.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filtered.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    proccessArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    print("start")
    var array = []
    for i in 0...arrProcessName.count{
        if(arrProcessName[safe: i] != nil && arrRequestedBy[safe: i] != nil && arrCreationTime[safe: i] != nil && arrStatus[safe: i] != nil)
        {
            var newProcess = Process(process: arrProcessName[i], requestor: arrRequestedBy[i], time: arrCreationTime[i], status: arrStatus[i])
            self.proccessArray.append(newProcess)
        }
    }
    print("array: ", proccessArray)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "status CONTAINS[c] %@", "pending")
    array = (proccessArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    print("array: ", array)
    let arr2 = (array as Array).map { $0 as? String ?? "" }
    filtered = arr2
    print("filtered: ", filtered)

    if(filtered.count == 0){
                    searchActive = false;
                } else {
                    searchActive = true;
                }
    tableView?.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    removeProgressBar()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HistoryCustomCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    if self.searchCtrler.active {
        print("processArray: ",proccessArray[indexPath.row].status as String!)
        cell.lbl_status.text = proccessArray[indexPath.row].status as String!
    } else {
        cell.lbl_request_name.text = arrProcessName[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_requested_by.text = "Requested by: " + arrRequestedBy[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_creation_time.text = arrCreationTime[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_status.text = arrStatus[indexPath.row]

        switch arrStatus[indexPath.row] {
            case "Completed", "Approved":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_approved")
            case "Running", "Processing", "Pending":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_pending")
            case "Denied", "Rejected":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_reject")
            case "Error":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_terminated")
            case "Retracted":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_retracted")
            default:
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

**Class Process**

```
import Foundation

class Process:NSObject{
var process: NSString!
var requestor: NSString!
var time: NSString!
var status: NSString!

init(process:NSString, requestor:NSString, time: NSString, status: NSString){
    self.process = process
    self.requestor = requestor
    self.time = time
    self.status = status
}

}
```

I have printed the array and the result is like this.

```
array:  (
   "< X.Process: 0x7f8bc94cfa50>"
)
```

After the conversion which is filtered. I get an empty array which hit me the **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION**.

Is there anyway to convert my `NSArray` to Swift Array without affect my data inside the NSArray?

Thank you

Comment: Please add tableView delegate methods contents

Comment: proccessArray is not contains string directly it may contains custom class object `Process`, and in filter array you try to convert it to optional `String` i.e the reason your filter array contains empty string object.

Comment: @NiravD so what i can do about it?

Comment: @DaveCruise You need to show only status when you are searching?

Comment: @NiravD no i need to show every detail like id:1, status:pending, country:TH.

Comment: @DaveCruise Then what is the meaning of this `.map { $0 as? String ?? "" }`?

Comment: @DaveCruise Also from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are only setting status label when your search is active.

Comment: @NiravD this is a way to convert NSArray to Swift array according to what i have found because I can't force the conversion by using as! String. I have no idea how the people that i referred in SOF can do it.

Comment: @NiravD that is for my testing purpose as I should be using filtered[indexPath.row].status instead of using processArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert Swift Array `[Process]` to `NSArray` just for filter, you can directly filter your `[Process]` array like this.

```
let filterProcess = self.proccessArray.filter { $0.status == "pending" }
```

In your case there is no need to use `contains` but if you want then:

```
let filterProcess = self.proccessArray.filter { $0.status.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("pending") }
```

Comment: i hit this error with cannot assign value of type '[Process]' to type '[String]'

Comment: this is my code "filtered = self.proccessArray.filter{ $0.status == "pending" }" may i know what is $0 mean?

Comment: @DaveCruise You need to declare your `filtered` also as `[Process]` not as `[String]` because you want whole process object

Comment: @DaveCruise it will iterate through whole array elements one by one and each will represent by `$0` one after another.

Comment: I still don't get result when i print my filtered.

Comment: I have edited my answer. should i change my process class with String instead of NSString by using ur way?

Comment: i get value of type 'NSString' has no member of localizedCaseInsensitiveContins

Comment: ya excellent but i have a situation now. even if i have added indexPath but the new page of the detail is not the same as the tableView show. pls help me. If u want i can have a new question again. ALSO, how do i have multiple search with your way instead of only status?

Comment: as in. search besides status. like i am able to search by name

Comment: @DaveCruise like this `filter { $0.status.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("pending") || $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("name") }`

Comment: you save my life. i have been struggling this about a week. thank you so much. much appreciate

Comment: @DaveCruise Welcome mate :)